# Como ocultar y posicionar etiquetas en JpGhraph

Tags: php, graph

Estoy realizando un reporte el cual se descarga en PDF utilizando la librería FPDF entre los datos que debe llevar esta la siguiente grafica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo la librería `JpGraph` para generar la imagen y guardarla como `.png` y después la llamo al archivo PDF. Mi grafica se descarga de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presento los siguientes problema:

1.- No esta respetando los colores que le asigno al grafico, yo necesito que el masculino sea un color azul fuerte y el femenino de color naranja.

2.- Los valores de la izquierda y las leyendas los muestra al revés.

3.- Los valores de la parte superior deseo ocultarlos ó eliminarlos.

4.- Necesito agregar las etiquetas a los datos en la graficas de `pie` si puedo pero en esta de `bar` no.

Este es el código de la función que genera la imagen de la grafica

```css
$data1=array(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -3, -9, -10, -21, -6, -5, 0);
$datax=array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 10, 15, 10, 4, 0);

$width=571; $height=334;
$graph = new Graph($width,$height);
$graph->SetScale('textlin');
$top = 60;
$bottom = 30;
$left = 30;
$right = -40;
$graph->Set90AndMargin($left,$right,$top,$bottom);
$graph->SetShadow();
$lbl = array("< 1 a","1 a 5 a","6 a 9 a","10 a 19 a","20 a 29 a","30 a 39 a","40 a 49 a","50 a 59 a","60 a 69 a","70 a 79 a","80 a 89 a","90 a 99 a");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($lbl);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_LEFT);
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAlign('right','center','right');
$graph->yaxis->SetLabelAlign('left','center');
$graph->title->Set('Grafica de defunciones en personal de salud');
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1);
$b1plot->SetWeight(0);
$b1plot->SetFillColor("#005ecd");
$b1plot->SetLegend("Masculino");
$b1plot->SetValuePos('center');
$b2plot = new BarPlot($datax);
$b2plot->SetWeight(0);
$b2plot->SetFillColor("#FF8C00");
$b2plot->SetLegend("Femenino");
$b2plot->SetValuePos('center');
$gbplot = new AccBarPlot(array($b1plot, $b2plot));
$graph->legend->SetPos(0.6,0.99,"center","bottom");
$graph->Add($gbplot);
unlink("grafica_bar.png");
$graph->Stroke("grafica_bar.png");
$this->Image("grafica_bar.png");
```

Espero me puedan ayudar ya que no encuentro mucha documentación de graficas parecidas, de antemano muchas gracias!

NOTA: En las etiquetas puse `Jgrapht` por que no me aparece la correcta que es `JpGraph` y no se como se puede agregar.

Comment: [¿Cómo puedo crear una nueva etiqueta?](/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: Ya lo leí pero aun no cuento con la reputación necesaria, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hechale una leida a esta respuesta en meta con respecto a la creación de etiquetas en StackOverflow https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/c%c3%b3mo-crear-o-solicitar-una-nueva-etiqueta

Comment: qué versión de jpGraph es esa?

Comment: Disculpa, como puedo saber la versión que estoy utilizando? al final de los archivos de la carpeta docs dice Generated at 20 Jul 2009 at 16:57